# Angular directive that will work like lisp macro but for html

Tags: angularjs

Can I have in directive same thing as in lisp macro, where I can access source html inside a element and based on it's html create new html that will be injected into the DOM?

And I get access to the html inside and create new template based on that html.

Is html -> html transformation is possible in Angular? From what I read it's not, but maybe there is some advanced use of the framework that will allow for this.

For instance I have code like this:

```
<directive>
   <ul>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
   </ul>
</directive>
```

and what output:

```
<directive>
   <ul>
      <li ng-hide="some-logic">Foo</li>
      <li ng-hide="some-other-logic">Bar</li>
   </ul>
</directive>
```

So what I need is template function that will get html as argument and return template that will have angular code.

```
template: function(source_xml) {
   return source_xml.find('li').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('ng-hide', '<SOME LOGIC>');
   });
}
```

There is a way to use $compile inside transclude function, but I'm not quite sure how to use it and if it will work as think.

Comment: I didn't understand a word :) Could you give an example (like "this input should produce that output") ?

Comment: In a way, directives are, themselves, the macros you're looking for. The more angular-native way of doing your example would be to make a directive for those `<li>` nodes and put whatever logic you need to set `ng-hide` on those elements in that directive.   (i.e. instead of thinking in terms of slurping up a whole chunk of HTML and using `.find()` to seek out bits and pieces of it to transform in various ways, think in terms of using a separate directive for each bit and piece that needs transforming, and nesting those directives where necessary.)

Comment: @DanielBeck the problem I'm trying to solve is that I need to inject (transclude) into 2 places and one place need to have ng-hide (in general need to have different angular stuff inside). I could use hide() (and use jQuery logic) but I can access elements if there is ng-repeat.

Comment: @jcubic I think you might be better off posting a new question that's more specific to whatever outcome you're trying to achieve; it's really difficult to make good recommendations for you without any details.    In general, though, angular can do a lot more of the work for you if you let it: think in terms of individual components each being their own directive, rather than having one top-down directive that tries to handle everything. (And it's almost never a good idea to resort to direct DOM manipulation via jQuery or otherwise; that generally leads to conflicts with Angular.)

Comment: @DanielBeck I can't write li or item directive, if only one parent directive know that it need to go into two places, and each one need to be hidden. I'm try to create resuable compontent here. So far I've created 4 different questions each rephrased, this one is general one. Where I'm asking what can be done in Angular. Here is exactly same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575596/how-to-modify-transcluded-content-before-compile-inside-directive

Comment: I'd take a look to this library: https://github.com/debonet/angular-macros